# How can Community offer bounties

Tags: support, bounty

[Why does American English pluralize certain singular nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/why-does-american-english-pluralize-certain-singular-nouns) has an open bounty of +500 from the Community. How does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's because a user had a bounty but requested deletion while the bounty was live.

Comment: Shouldn't the bounty be removed, in that case? How is the Community user going to award it, after all?

Comment: @Martha It'll happen as an auto-award (half bounty to the highest voted answer (min. score of 2) posted after the bounty was started) after it expires.

Comment: @martha that's covered in the http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty rules for sure, see the bulleted list at the bottom there.